# $\int_{a}^bf(t)h(t)dt=-\int_a^bF(t)h'(t) dt$ where $F$ is primite function of $f$ and $h(a)=h(b)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I have to prove that: $$\int_{a}^bf(t)h(t)dt=-\int_a^bF(t)h'(t) dt$$
Where $F(x)=\int_a^x f(s)ds$, and $h(t) \in C^1([a,b])$ such that $h(a)=h(b)=0$.
Not really sure how to approach this one, i guess i should use Newton-Leibniz formula somehow, but not sure how.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Comment: $${\rm Hint:} \quad \int_a^b f(t)h(t)dt + \int_a^b F(t)h'(t)dt = \int_a^b \frac d{dt}\Big( F(t)h(t) \Big) dt$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple application of Integration by Parts.
$$
\int_{a}^b f(t)h(t)dt = [F(t)h(t)]_{a}^b - \int_{a}^b F(t)h'(t)dt
$$
you conclude using $h(a)=h(b)=0$.